# c++ change directory and run make

Tags: c++

i have this code

```
 switch(fork()){
        case -1: perror("fork");
          exit(1);
        case 0:
          if(chdir("cd /var/code/p1"))
          system("make");
          break;
        default: 
          break;
        }
```

in /var/code/p1 is a make file and a code file (if i tipe make in this directory its work) , this code is in /var/code/p2.

My problem is : this code is not compile the code from /var/code/p1, this are compile the code from /var/code/p2 , so what i do wrong?

Comment: If you intend on using mainly command line programs, C++ might not be the most appropriate tool. That being said: `system( "make -C /var/code/p1" )` will run `make` in `/var/code/p1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
chdir("cd /var/code/p1")
```

should be

```
chdir("/var/code/p1")
```

And the if test is incorrect since chdir returns 0 on success. You need

```
if (chdir("/var/code/p1") == 0)
       system("make");
```

Comment: ieah you are right , the first time i tray with system("cd /var/code/p1;make") and i just copy and paste the code